# Getting mouse clicked position and instantiate a div in that location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've got a div inside of my parent div

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.parent{     
width: calc(100% - 299px);
height: calc(100% - 78px);
display: inline-block;
overflow: scroll;
.child {
  width:1500px;
  height: 2500px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
 }
```

when i click the mouse on the child element i want to get the mouse position in the child element so min is 0-0 max is 1500-2500
then when i click i want to create a div in that clicked position how can i do that ?
// jquery is preferred

Answer (score 0):

To get coordinates you can try:

```
$('.child').click(function(e) {
    alert(e.pageX+ ' , ' + e.pageY);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The mouse position within an element is the event's offsetX and offsetY (and Y is min at the top and max at the bottom of the screen). The position of the new element would also need to take into account the parent's position, so its left and top coordinates are added (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psp3fv3z/1/)):

```
$(".child").on("click", function(event) {
    alert("Mouse position within child div: X: " + event.offsetX +
  ", Y:" + event.offsetY);
  var offX = $(this).css("left");
  var offY = $(this).css("top");
  var styles = {
   left : event.offsetX + parseInt(offX) + "px",
   top: event.offsetY + parseInt(offY) + "px"
  };
  $(this).append("div").addClass("grandchild").css(styles);
});
```